# ImageView Images Displaying as White Square

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm new to this and can't figure out what's wrong with my images. When I added them to the `drawable` folder, I right-clicked on `res` and chose `New > Image Asset`. During preview, the none of the 4 images displayed, but only showed a white box. They are all 100px square images and in `.png` format. I have no errors in my code and my app runs with no errors. But the ImageView is still just a white square, no matter which image I try to display. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/imageView"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/imageView"
        android:id="@+id/picImageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/BMIPicture"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/imageView"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/imageView"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/imageView"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/imageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/answerTextView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/maxWeightTV"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/maxWeightTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop" />
```

Implementing the ImageView in Java:

```
bmiPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picImageView);
bmiPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.scale);
```

Comment: Change `bmiPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.scale);` to `bmiPicture.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("scale",
            "drawable", getPackageName()));`

Comment: @callOfCode that doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @musikluver2003 I face the same issue and can't figure out whats wrong. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Not sure if it solves the OP's issue as their picture was a `PNG` but it may help someone else who ends up here. I just had a similar issue with a ImageView showing a white square on a Huawei Ale-L02 but not on any other phone I tested on. Issue ended up being that the phone didn't like images in `GIF` format, once I changed the images to `PNG` they displayed fine

Comment: @musikluver2003 Did you ever fix the issue? Have you tried setting the image via XML?